# How do you create a 'Folder Shortcut' in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, network-shares, shortcuts, windows-2000

I need to create a 'Folder Shortcut' in Windows Explorer in Windows 2000.  I don't mean a mapped drive, just a Folder Shortcut to a shared network folder (it will end up as a first-level object under My Network Places).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, figured it out.

Go to the 'My Network Places' folder, and double-click on 'Add Network Places', then just browse for the folder and hit OK.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the folder and select "Create Shortcut".
Move the shortcut to wherever.

Comment: I've tried that, doesn't work.  It won't let me place it under Network Neighborhood in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You see 'Favorites' section in left pane.

Drag your folder and drop it in this 'Favorites' section.

A link (shortcut) will be created in the tree structure of 'Favorites'.

Next time you start windows explorer - you can just open your folder by clicking the icon in this Favorites section.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the folder. Click Send To, then click Desktop. Move that shortcut wherever you want it.

Comment: It won't move to the 'My Network Place' folder (though there already Folder Shortcuts there, so there must be a way).